# Link to the last action within the active tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, last-activity

<sup>*Orginal question below the update*</sup>

### **Update**

The answer below was helpful but it wasn't clear for me that we can click those links. We can maybe consider changing their colors so they behave more like links than normal text since they are different from the other tabs.

I have also tested more texts seeking for hidden links and I found another useful one within questions that helps to find the last activity of it. Of course I never thought about clicking on it before.

[image]

So maybe a more generic feature request for this question would be: **change color of some links and make them different than normal text so they are more visible as links.**

---

### **Original Question**

I didn't find a good title for this purpose but here is a detailed explanation of what I want.

This is about the active tab related to the questions

[image]

We all know that this tab will show us questions based on their activities:

- Asked question
- Modified question (or any of its answers)
- Answered question

But in all the cases, the link will always redirect **to the question** (top of the page) which is a bit annoying for me as I have to find where the modification was done or where is the new answer:

[image]

So my question is: **why we don't update the links of active tab to redirect them based on the action made?**

If it's a new asked question we keep the default link as it is.

If it's a new answer, we redirect to this answer.

If it's a modification, we redirect to the modified answer or we keep the default link if the modification is done on the question.

---

So it will be either for **the question** or for **an answer** and in my opinion it should not be difficult to implement since a link of an answer is a simple addition of an ID at the end.

[image]

***NB:*** I know that we can click on the active tab within the question in order to easily find the new answer or the last modifed answer, but it's not very intuitive for me and the above feature can make it easier.

Comment: If you click on the word "answered" or "modified" it takes you to the exact post...

Comment: @Catija true, didn't even notice it was a link, so another non-intuitive thing for me as it's a link only on the active tab

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I specifically prefer that the question title link remain as-is. I intentionally use it sometimes if I haven't read the question at all yet and I want to read the entire post. Having it randomly link to either the question or one of the answers would be really confusing to me and (I expect) to many users who don't notice the differing action types (asked/answered/modified).

As I noted in the comments, the feature you want is already built in, though it seems you weren't aware of it. Clicking, instead, on the word "modified" or "answered" takes you directly to the most-recent activity on that post - the reason it was bumped up on the "active" list. This is great and it's a feature that I use so much I miss the fact that it *doesn't* have an equivalent in the iOS Stack Exchange App.

Hopefully being aware of it will help. If there are many users who don't know about the feature, it might make sense to make it more obvious in the UI by matching the blue of links everywhere else on the page. The pale grey doesn't scream "click me, I'm a link", particularly as it nearly matches the color of the user's reputation, which is *not* a link. It does currently change color on hover to the blue, though.

Comment: yes, your comment was helpful as I never thought about clicking there, but now it's easy ... and I agree that we should at least change it's color as it's the same everywhere in all the website and clickable only in the active tab